# Возникнут ли проблемы при выгрузки приложения, которое связано с уведомлениями с сервера Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Собираюсь выгружать приложение в AppStore, в котором присутствуют Push notification от Firebase, на данный момент на устройстве уведомления работают, когда я оправляю их с сервера. Но боюсь что может где то надо переключить к примеру с debug на public или еще что то ? Кто сталкивался? Могу ли я смело выгружать? или же надо где то что то переключить именно перед выгрузкой ? Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging

в AppDelegate нужно прописать метод:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)
}
```

для выгрузки в App Store надо прописать это

```
FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod
```

для тестирования на устройствах надо прописать это

```
FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox
```

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое это сделать `production build` и потестировать. И тогда Вы точно будите знать, работает или нет.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а можно чуть подробнее описать процесс, я не совсем понял, спасибо.